# How to colour a variable in PSObject output

Tags: powershell

How can I colour in red only the variable $server?

Something like  Add-Member Noteproperty -name Server -value (Write-Host $server -foregroundcolour red)

```
$object = New-Object PSObject
$object | Add-Member Noteproperty -name User -value $user
$object | Add-Member Noteproperty -name Server -value $server
$object |fl
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone wants to know, if your console supports [VT (Virtual Terminal) escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#text-formatting), you can use it directly.

The original post uses [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object?view=powershell-5.1), which is considered the [legacy approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-5.1#legacy-approach).  Therefore, in my example I will use the [`[PSCustomObject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-5.1) type to convert an  `[ordered]hashtable`.

For the VT colors, I referenced a [StackExchange's SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/a/1105718/1121695) I found.
Also, I add `ESC[0m` (in the form of `$esc[0m`) to the end of the VT command to reset the color.

```
# Grab some data to work with
# NOTE: This grabs either the domain name or Windows workgroup name
$domain = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName "Win32_ComputerSystem").Domain

$boolDomainJoined = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName "Win32_ComputerSystem").PartOfDomain

# VT (Virtual Terminal) escape sequences
$esc = [char]27
$grayDark = 90
$greenBright = 92
$redBright = 91

# New empty object
$objHT = [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{}

# Get fancy and even colorize the custom property name
$objHT | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "$esc[${grayDark}m$("Computer name")$esc[0m" -Value $env:COMPUTERNAME

# Check if computer is part of a domain
if ($boolDomainJoined) {
    $objHT | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Domain" -Value "$esc[${greenBright}m$($domain)$esc[0m"
} else {
    $objHT | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Workgroup" -Value "$esc[${redBright}m$($domain)$esc[0m"
}

# Display object as a list
$objHT | Format-List
```

#### Output:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box you cannot. Colouring, or `-ForegroundColor` and `-BackgroundColor` switches, are only available on `Write-Host` cmdlet.
You would have to write a custom function which processes values from `$object` and writes them to console using `Write-Host`.